# I'm getting an errror while installing faker, what should I do?

Tags: python, faker

I'm getting an error while installing Faker in python, what should I do?

error:

```
six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, Faker
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: pip install Faker --ignore-installed six --user ? or no --user this may work

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in here

> It is a distutils installed project

You probably have already installed this package use something like os package manager (something like `apt`). Thus, you should use that to remove it.

On the particular topic. You might want to use virtualenv to manage this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall six using `sudo apt-get remove six` and then install `Faker` again

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the installed projects by using `--ignore-installed`

For example, try `pip install Faker --ignore-installed`